# GND polygon in Altium

Tags: altium

after routing a PCB I've added a GND polygon like :

[image]

My question is why some GND Pin aren't connected to the  Polygon ? should I connect them manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why some GND Pin aren't connected to the Polygon?

Because your clearance rule does not allow the polygon to reach the pins. Try reducing the clearance and see how that changes.

Also, you have unconnected islands in your polygon (called "Dead Copper"). This can cause you issues, as the polygon looks good, but is not actually connected to anything. You can remove these islands from the polygon properties menu.

Comment: @Atmandas thanks for you answer I've change the clearance rule it worked for some pins, should route the rest manually ?  would it be ok ?

Comment: @Engine Yes, you can always route it manually.